# Появляется cmd вместе с messagebox

Tags: ассемблер, messagebox

Подскажите, пожалуйста,почему при завершении программы появляется вместе с мессенджером командная строка?

И если Вам не сложно подскажите, правильно ли я сделала задание: разработать процедуру, проверяющую, превосходит ли сумма двух чисел третье число.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
includelib Y:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib Y:\masm32\lib\user32.lib

ExitProcess PROTO       ,:DWORD
MessageBoxA PROTO ,:DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD 

.data
Caption db "Lab6", 0
MyStr db "No", 0
MsgBoxCaption2 db "Lab6", 0
MsgBoxText2 db "Yes", 0

.const
a = 3
b = 4
d = 5

.code
Winmain PROC

Check proc
    mov eax, a
    mov ebx, b
    add eax, ebx
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov ebx, d
    cmp eax, ebx
    ja next
    jmp exit

next:
    mov eax, a
    mov ebx, d
    add eax, ebx
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov ebx, b
    cmp eax, ebx
    ja last
    jmp exit

last:
    mov eax, b
    mov ebx, d
    add eax, ebx
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov ebx, a
    cmp eax, ebx
    ja message
    jmp exit

exit:
    push 0
    push offset Caption
    push offset MyStr
    push 0
    call MessageBoxA

    push 0
    call ExitProcess

message:
    push 0
    push offset MsgBoxCaption2
    push offset MsgBoxText2
    push 0
    call MessageBoxA

    push 0
    call ExitProcess

Check endp

Winmain endp
end Winmain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему вы собираете программу, не как  консольное приложение windows. При запуске таких приложений из командной строки они начинают выполняться независимо от запустившей их консоли. Например запустите из командной строки notepad, вы увидите открывшееся окно редактора, а cmd тут же станет свободна и не будет дожидаться пока он завершиться. Так же и с вашей программой, cmd только запускает ее и тут же освобождается, поэтому cmd уже готова принимать новую команду еще до того как выведен MessageBox.

По тексту программы: Я бы лично текст задачи по другому понял, но если задача проверить, что из 3х чисел сумма любых двух больше либо равна третьему, то логика верна. Правда много лишних действий. `xor ebx, ebx` (т.е. обнуление ebx) перед занесением в него другой переменной не нужно, она и так отлично затрет предыдущее значение. Инструкции `add` и `cmp` могут работать не только с парой регистров, но и с одним регистром и одним значением (или регистром и ячейкой памяти). Команду перехода стоит заменить на противоположную, что бы происходил условный переход на выход. А в случае успеха никаких переходов не делать, а просто продолжать. Ввиду перечисленного основной блок операций можно было бы записать так:

```
mov eax, a
add eax, b
cmp eax, d
jna exit

mov eax, a
...
```

Ну и если задание сделать процедуру, наверное стоит показать и вызов этой процедуры. Пусть даже все числа в ней будут константами и она сама выводит сообщение (хотя так редко в жизни делают, процедуры обычно делают для многократного использования в разных ситуациях и тогда надо что бы числа могли быть изменены при каждом вызове, т.е. переданы параметрами). Выглядеть это будет так:

```
Winmain PROC
    call Check        ; Вызываем процедуру
    push 0
    call ExitProcess  ; И завершаем программу
Winmain endp

Check proc
   ....
   call MessageBoxA   ; Выводим сообщение
   ret                ; и возвращаем управление в вызвавший код
Check endp
```